# how to use substring with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do substring with LINQ but I always get an error.

I fetch data from JS view side to `IActionResult` Controller side as IFormCollection. the data is displaying one model twice.

here is the model

```
public class PostAssignment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Indx { get; set; }
    public string QuestionHintGuid { get; set; }
    public string QuestionHintAnswer { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }

}
```

and here is how it is fetched data and retrieve the form twice with different keys such as `-0` or `-1`

[image]

then, I loop through this data to save each model independently

```
    public IActionResult CreateQuestionesImg(IFormCollection data)
    {
        ICollection<string> keys = data.Keys;
        List<PostAssignment> pas = new List<PostAssignment>();
        int result = 0;
        int FormId = 0;
        int loopCount = (data.Keys.Count() -1) / 5; // = 2 "number of forms" 
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {

            PostAssignment pa = new PostAssignment();
            pa.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            
            // here where the problem comes
            var GroupedIForm = data.Where(w => w.Key.Split("-")[1] == FormId.ToString()).Select(s => s);                                                                                                                                                               
 
            foreach (var item in GroupedIForm)
            {
                // bla bla bla
                pas.Add(pa);
            }
            FormId += 1;
        }

        _context.AddRange(pas);
        result = _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(result);
    }
```

finally, it gets this error

[image]

based on this data in the first picture why my LINQ gives me that error?

Comment: Some for the keys in `data`  don’t have `-`

Comment: If you're gonna split on `-`, it helps to make sure the data contains it first.. `data.Where(w => w.Contains("-") && w.Key.Split("-")[1] == FormId.ToString()).Select(s => s);` but for my money I think I'd just do `data.Where(w => w.Key.EndsWith("-"+FormId).Select(s => s);` - even better, form the `"-"+FormId` outside of the where. Splitting is heavy compared to checking if a string has a couple of chars at the end

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is that

```
w.Key.Split("-")
```

returns just `1` item and that's why `[1]` is out of bound in

```
w.Key.Split("-")[1].
```

You can try

```
.Split('-', 3).ElementAtOrDefault(1)
```

fragement istead. Here we use

- `'-'` instead of `"-"` for a (micro)optimization: char is enough
- `3` - we require at most `3` parts splitting
- `ElementAtOrDefault(1)` - we have either value or `null` when the split is too short

```
var GroupedIForm = data
  .Where(w => w
     .Key
     .Split('-', 3)
     .ElementAtOrDefault(1) == FormId.ToString())
  .Select(s => s);
```